# Gradle dependency does not work as my expectation

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have two sub projects subproject1 and subproject2. I'd like to add some classes from subproject2 to subproject1 and get the subproject1.jar. Below is my gradle file:

```
task copyClasses (dependsOn: [  ':subproject1:clean',  ':subproject1:classes']) {
    println "copyClasses "
    doLast {
        Task study = tasks.getByPath(':subproject1:jar')
        study.doFirst {
            copy {
                println "copy ... "
                println sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
                println project(':subproject1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
                from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
                into project(':subproject1').sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
            }
        }
    }
}

task jarUpdated (dependsOn: [ clean, classes, copyClasses, ':subproject1:jar']) {
    doLast {
        println "jarUpdated"
    }
}
```

But I got the build sequence as below:

```
$ gradle jarUpdated
copyClasses
:subproject1:compileJava
:subproject1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:subproject1:classes
:subproject1:jar
:subproject2:compileJava
:subproject2:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:subproject2:classes
:subproject2:clean
:subproject1:clean
:subproject2:copyClasses
Calling Task.doFirst(Closure) after task execution has started has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Check the configuration of task ':subproject1:jar'.
:subproject2:jarUpdated
jarUpdated

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

My expectation is:

```
$ gradle jarUpdated
:subproject2:clean 
:subproject2:compileJava
:subproject2:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:subproject2:classes
:subproject1:clean 
:subproject1:compileJava
:subproject1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:subproject2:copyClasses
copyClasses
copy ... 
:subproject1:jar 
:subproject2:jarUpdated
jarUpdated

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Would you please suggest or point out what I missed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The build script has a number of problems. I recommend to create the fat Jar with a plugin such as https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin or https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser thanks for your comments. I actually want to extend the jar of subproject1 to add some classes from subproject2. So I changed the task(':subproject1:jar').

Comment: That won't solve the problems. Tasks cannot create/execute other tasks. The order of tasks after `dependsOn` is *not* significant. `println "copyClasses"` needs to go inside `doLast`. And projects shouldn't reach out into the project model of other projects (`project(':subproject1').sourceSets`). The easiest way to fix these problems is to use one of the plugins I mentioned.

Comment: I thought tasks after dependsOn should execute in order.

Comment: This is true in Ant, but not in Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easiest" way to do exactly what you asked for is probably something like this in your subproject1 build file.

```
jar {
  from  tasks.getByPath(':subproject2:compileJava')
}
```

However this is a very simplistic approach with a LOT of caveats, for example

- Subproject 1 can not compile against subproject 2 classes
- Any dependencies of Subproject 2 will not be included
- etc

I would actually advise declaring subproject2 as a dependency of subproject1 and using one of the plugins that Peter suggested.